# Inserting a logo with css

Tags: css, svg

I have the following html

`<a class=logo></a>`

I want to replace it with my logo.  But I want the logo to take up 100% of the vertical room, and an amount of horizontal room that will leave the image proportional

I could try to do

```
.logo {
  background-image: 'logo.svg';
  background-size: auto 100%;
}
```

except I would still need to set a `height` and `width` in order for it to take up space.

I could try to do

```
.logo:before {
  content: url('logo.svg');
}
```

except the only way to set the height and width of the image is with

```
zoom: X%
```

or

```
transform: scale(50%);
```

and neither of these will react to changing heights

Is there any other way I'm missing?

Edit: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2HKc4/) - how can I get the width correct here?

Comment: You should be using `<span>` instead of `<a>`.

Comment: Did you try background-size:contain;?

Comment: How about posting a fiddle?... could get you an answer a lot quicker

Comment: @RahulDesai why? an anchor tag is just as legitimate if he want's it to be clickable.

Comment: @RCorrie He is not acutally linking anywere with the `<a>` tag.

Comment: @RahulDesai A logo will normally link to the home page. I'm assuming this is a stripped down example to focus on the issue at hand.

Comment: Yeah, I took out the href='/' as it didn't seem germane

Comment: background-size:contain is useful, but I would still need to know the width

Answer (score 2):

If you're wanting a proportional box with 100% width and a height that matches the aspect ratio of the background-image, set the vertical padding to a percentage that matches the vertical ratio.

i.e. if your logo is a 2:1 rectangle, set your width to 100% and your padding to `25% 0` and your  tag will stay proportionally sized (you'll need to set it to `display: block;`). Then `background-size: 100% auto` (or the other way around) should work because the background image's aspect ratio is the same as its container.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K2h7s/1/)

Comment: I need it to be the other way around; 100% height, and a width to match the aspect ratio :-/

Comment: Another problem with this approach:

setting the `padding: 25% 0;` doesn't ensure a proportionally size block.  The 25% is a percent of the containing element, which is not constant in this case

Comment: yes this will only work if it fills 100% of the containing element.